# Read more or read less, needs to be clicked twice to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a read more or lead less div with HTML and vanilla javascript. Everything works, but I have to click the button twice for some reasons to show the text, and from there it works great.

So the issue is, button needs to be clicked twice at first to show the content. From there it works great.

HTML File

```js
<div id="test">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>

<button onclick="test()" id="testBtn">Read more</button>
```

On css file test is `display:none`

JS file

```js
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("testBtn");

    if (test.style.display !== "none") {
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
        test.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
        test.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is actually not reproducible for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1yvcohn7/

Comment: the element.style.display is only getting/modifying inline css, but there is no inline css for your `<div id="test">`, thats why during the first time click, the `test.style.display` is not equals to `"none"`, because its empty

Comment: On the first click `test.style.display` isn't set so it gets set to "none". Note that test.style.display is not the same thing as the computed style of the element, so it can be display none while test.style.display is empty.

Comment: @DanielW. They are setting the style in a CSS file rather than inline, which is causing the issue with JS's `.style`

Comment: @DBS I see - so we'd have to read some `getComputedStyle` value instead. I'd expect the styles from the external CSS being taken into the DOM. Edit: The better approach would be to work with `data` or `class` attributes instead of manipulating the styles directly.